# How to install Specific version of Spacy

Tags: python, installation, nlp, version, spacy

I am trying to install spacy version 2.0.0 it starts downloading, but can not install and give this error.

```
Found existing installation: cymem 2.0.5
Uninstalling cymem-2.0.5:
  Successfully uninstalled cymem-2.0.5
Running setup.py install for cymem ... error
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
 command: 'c:\users\taqi\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\TAQI\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-o890sm67\\cymem_134557a3656d414d8545e96d491823df\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\TAQI\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-o890sm67\\cymem_134557a3656d414d8545e96d491823df\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\TAQI\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-oa_pr0r9\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\taqi\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\Include\cymem'
     cwd: C:\Users\TAQI\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-o890sm67\cymem_134557a3656d414d8545e96d491823df\
Complete output (17 lines):
running install
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cymem
copying cymem\about.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cymem
copying cymem\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cymem
package init file 'cymem\tests\__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cymem\tests
copying cymem\tests\test_import.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cymem\tests
copying cymem\cymem.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cymem
copying cymem\cymem.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cymem
copying cymem\__init__.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cymem
running build_ext
building 'cymem.cymem' extension
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
----------------------------------------
```

Rolling back uninstall of cymem
Moving to c:\users\taqi\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\cymem-2.0.5.dist-info
from C:\Users\TAQI\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages~ymem-2.0.5.dist-info
Moving to c:\users\taqi\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\cymem
from C:\Users\TAQI\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages~ymem
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\taqi\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\TAQI\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-o890sm67\cymem_134557a3656d414d8545e96d491823df\setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'C:\Users\TAQI\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-o890sm67\cymem_134557a3656d414d8545e96d491823df\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**) if os.path.exists(**file**) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\TAQI\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-oa_pr0r9\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\taqi\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\Include\cymem' Check the logs for full command output.

Comment: Have you tried installing Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater?

Comment: No, I already had install version 3 spacy due to some code I need version 2, I uninstalled the previous version and now can not install version 2, my python version is 3.9.6

Comment: You don't understand me. The last line of the error callback is error: `Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/`

Answer (score 4):

You're trying to install a version that's fairly old (from 2017) and doesn't have binary wheels for python 3.9 (released in 2020). Actually it doesn't have any binary wheels even for older versions of python, so to install it you'd definitely need a compiler. This is probably not what you want.

If you want spaCy v2 instead of spaCy v3, install like this to get the most recent v2.x release (without having to know the exact version number):

```sh
pip install "spacy~=2.0"
```

This is currently `spacy==2.3.7`.

Similarly, if you need a specific minor version of v2 like v2.3, you can also use `~=` to specify that:

```sh
pip install "spacy~=2.3.0"
```

There are only python 3.9 wheels starting at v2.3.3. Otherwise you'll need to install a compiler as described in the docs: https://spacy.io/usage#source

Comment: Thank you so much best explanation. Then how to install this (version 2.3.6 or 2.3.7) in the Jupyter notebook using Anaconda? Your solution worked and I could install it but now can't import to jupyter notebook.

Comment: When I type pip show spacy in cmd. it shows information about spacy but can not import in Jupyter or Pycharm

Comment: Usually you can install within jupyter with `!python -m pip install ...` and then restart the runtime.